# Problem installing BIMP

Tags: software-installation, updates, graphics, vector

I've installed on my pc GIMP version 2.8.22 and it seems to be the latest version. When I try to install BIMP I get this error.

```
libgimp2.0-dev : Depends: libgtk2.0-dev (>= 2.12.5) but it is not going to be installed
```

I should get the 2.12.5 version for install BIMP? Thanks in advance!

Comment: get libgtk2.0-dev

Comment: Just Done...but not working...installing libgtk2.0-dev I get this --> https://pastebin.com/c3dy2VH1

Comment: install those dependencies also. this could be a long chain. if yu use aptitude to install it will automatically add dependencies

Comment: It's impossible..also wit aptitude cause for each dependencies to install I have other  3/4 other problem on dependecies..How can I do?

Comment: you will run into the same problem doing it manually. aptitude is the easiest way to figure it out

Comment: There is some special command for aptitude?

Comment: do you have it installed?

Comment: Yes I just installed

Comment: `sudo aptitude`